# Using a PreparedStatement to specify the column name and the new value

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to make a query with a PreparedStatement like this:

```
UPDATE PLAYER SET ? = ? WHERE ID = ?
```

but I get

> Error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01747

When I use code like this:

```
UPDATE PLAYER SET NAME = ? WHERE ID = ?
```

It works. However, I want to use 3 arguments in my method. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think you can replace objects with parameters.

Comment: Test with upper code is working but with errors.

Comment: Why not just include logic in your Java code to determine which column to update?  Or, better yet, craft the logic of your query to handle this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PreparedStatement: Can I use the column name as parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514981/preparedstatement-can-i-use-the-column-name-as-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by PreparedStatement by itself

you can use string.replace but thats exactly what you should avoid when using preparedStatement (for sql injections)

if you are using Hibernate you can jump to Criteria and this would be very easy to do